# Hovering the top bar maximizes window

Tags: 14.04, compiz, window

I have CompizConfig Manager installed, Grid enabled by default (I like it).

But if I have a window open half way and **hover at the top black bar it maximizes the window**. Does anyone know where I can change that option?

Im using 14 LTS, it's pretty amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CompizConfig Manager->Grid->tab "Corners/Edges": change "Top Edge" to none.